# The file “xxxx.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

Hello I am getting the below error. Anyone knows what the common problem and solution is?

```
Error Message: The file “xxxx.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format.
Error Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Recovery Suggestion: The file might be corrupted, truncated, or in an unexpected format.
```

Note: I am using M1 laptop

It happens after the following code execution:

```
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStack(withAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed: name)
```

Comment: Could you please add more context and describe your scenario? Are you using Core Data? At which point are you getting an error? Is it reproducible on just one particular device or simulator or across many of them?

Comment: Yes I am using coreDate, it is across simulators and devices. I have added the code execution block

Comment: I see you're using MagicalRecord which is an old and unsupported framework. Are you by chance trying to build an app from a codebase that wasn't updated for a long time?

Comment: It has recently been updated, I am not getting compilation error or even runtime error. I am just not getting the data because the data is in the sqlite file.

Comment: What does the `file` command say your database file is?

Comment: Have you tried to access the database using the terminal or with an app like DB Browser for SQLite to check if the db file actually is corrupted?

Comment: I have tried to open the file using Mac App but the file its empty DB. Can you provide  guide on how to open the file from terminal? thank you. I believe if there are any errors, that will be shown on terminal too. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: You can start with [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have done so, .open xxx.sqlite returns nothing. And .databases returns an error which says  "Error: file is not a database". My program is intending to create a sqlite database and write to it, then fetch from it subsequently.